# Am I happy or sad?

Tags: code-golf

You are trying to guess my emotion.

I will give you an adjective, as the input to the function/program.

Your task is to output my emotion, either `:)` for happy, or `:(` for sad.

## Details

For these adjectives, you must output the happy face `:)`

```
contented
delighted
merry
overjoyed
pleased
blessed
chipper
content
convivial
gleeful
gratified
intoxicated
jolly
light
peppy
perky
playful
sparkling
sunny
```

For these adjectives, you must output the sad face `:(`

```
melancholy
bitter
somber
dismal
mournful
blue
dejected
despairing
despondent
disconsolate
distressed
down
downcast
gloomy
glum
heavyhearted
lugubrious
morbid
morose
troubled
bereaved
```

Other adjectives are undefined. You may output whatever you want for other adjectives.

## Specs

- All in lowercase. All matches regex `^[a-z]+$`.

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest solution in bytes wins.

## Tips

There is a trick.

Comment: This isn't very interesting, basically `is input in this set`.

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ Well, `input.length % 2` is even less interesting...

Comment: The problem with this type of question is that once the bag, you have a completely different challenge.

Comment: _melancholy_ is not an adjective

Comment: @LuisMendo Come on.

Comment: @LuisMendo turning it to `melancholiac` can still keep the rule going, besides i think it is an adj

Comment: `Melancholy` **is** an adjective.

Answer (score 2):

### CJam, 9 bytes

```
':q,"()"=
```

The "trick" is the parity of the word lengths.

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qN%2F%7B%3AQ%3B%0A%0A'%3AQ%2C%22()%22%3D%0A%0A%5DoNo%7D%2F&input=contented%0Adelighted%0Amerry%0Aoverjoyed%0Apleased%0Ablessed%0Achipper%0Acontent%0Aconvivial%0Agleeful%0Agratified%0Aintoxicated%0Ajolly%0Alight%0Apeppy%0Aperky%0Aplayful%0Asparkling%0Asunny%0Amelancholy%0Abitter%0Asomber%0Adismal%0Amournful%0Ablue%0Adejected%0Adespairing%0Adespondent%0Adisconsolate%0Adistressed%0Adown%0Adowncast%0Agloomy%0Aglum%0Aheavyhearted%0Alugubrious%0Amorbid%0Amorose%0Atroubled%0Abereaved)

#### Explanation

```
':     e# Push character ':'.
q,     e# Get length of input.
"()"=  e# Using length as cyclic index into "()", giving '(' for even lengths
       e# and ')' for odd lengths.
```

Comment: Could you share with us how you discovered the trick?

Comment: @KennyLau By looking at the inputs I guess. It's fairly obvious (visually) that your word lengths are always taking steps in multiples of 2.

Comment: @MartinBüttner speak for yourself, I would never notice that.

Comment: @Bálint Well I wouldn't have either if I hadn't been looking for it, due to Kenny's hint.

Comment: me too i wudnt notice, was wastin my time finding connection between ascii patterns

Answer (score 2):

## Retina, <s>21</s> <s>18</s> 14 bytes

```
(..)+
:(
\(.
)
```

3 bytes saved thanks to [Martin Büttner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-b%C3%BCttner). Another 4 saved thanks to [Kenny Lau](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48934/kenny-lau).

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JShHYAooLi4pKwo6KApcKC4KKQ&input=Y29udGVudGVkCmRlbGlnaHRlZAptZXJyeQpvdmVyam95ZWQKcGxlYXNlZApibGVzc2VkCmNoaXBwZXIKY29udGVudApjb252aXZpYWwKZ2xlZWZ1bApncmF0aWZpZWQKaW50b3hpY2F0ZWQKam9sbHkKbGlnaHQKcGVwcHkKcGVya3kKcGxheWZ1bApzcGFya2xpbmcKc3VubnkKbWVsYW5jaG9seQpiaXR0ZXIKc29tYmVyCmRpc21hbAptb3VybmZ1bApibHVlCmRlamVjdGVkCmRlc3BhaXJpbmcKZGVzcG9uZGVudApkaXNjb25zb2xhdGUKZGlzdHJlc3NlZApkb3duCmRvd25jYXN0Cmdsb29teQpnbHVtCmhlYXZ5aGVhcnRlZApsdWd1YnJpb3VzCm1vcmJpZAptb3Jvc2UKdHJvdWJsZWQKYmVyZWF2ZWQ) (The first line is just to make it run for all test cases).

Uses the same approach as [Martins answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/79023/34543).

Answer (score 2):

## Brainfuck, 71 bytes

```
+[--------->+<]>+.>,+[[-]>[->+<]+>[<->-]<<,+]>[<<+>>-]<+++[<------>-]<.
```

Assumes that `EOF = -1`.

Explaination:

The first part, `+[--------->+<]>+.`, prints `:` and stores its ascii value (58) in `cell #2`.

The second part, `>,+[[-]>[->+<]+>[<->-]<<,+]`, is a bit more complicated. For each character in the input, it moves the value in `cell #4` into `cell #5`, it adds one to `cell #4`, and sets `cell #4 = cell #4 - cell #5`. Basically, what this does is it changes `cell #4` into `1 - cell #4`. When every character has been read, cell #4 is `length of input % 2`.

The third part, `>[<<+>>-]` adds the value of `cell #4` to `cell #2`.

The last part, `>,+[[-]>[->+<]+>[<->-]<<,+]` subtracts 18, which is the difference in the ascii table from the colon and the left parentesens  from `cell #2` and prints it.

Answer (score 2):

## MATL,  <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
58')('jn)h
```

1 byte saved thanks to @Luis's tip to just rely upon modular indexing rather than an explicit modulus.

[**Try it Online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=NTgnKSgnam4paA&input=Y29udGVudGVk)

**Explanation**

```
58      % Number literal (ASCII for ':')
')('    % String literal
j       % Explicitly grab input as string
n       % Compute the length of the input string
)       % Index into ')(' using modular indexing
h       % Horizontally concatenate ':' with the result
        % Implicitly display resulting string
```

Comment: `58')('jn)h` saves 1 byte using modular indexing

Comment: @LuisMendo Modular indexing gets me every time! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## J, 15 bytes

```
':',"0'()'{~2|#
```

`':',"0` concats `':'` with the 0-cells of the string `'()'`, making an array of `:(` and `:)`. `{~` is get with switched argument order, `2|` is the parity of the length `#` of the RHS.

```
  p =: ':',"0'()'{~2|#
  p 'happy'
:)
  p 'somber'
:(
```

Use `(>;p)"0` to test a list of words and compare their output.

Comment: What does `prozac` mean?

Comment: @KennyLau Bad pun. `prozac` is a depression medicine :P

Comment: Hahaha, made me laugh for a bit :p

Comment: @Adnan Yeah, but I guess it's not the apt place :P

Answer (score 2):

## Reng v.3.3, 12 bytes

```
":("k2,+roo~
```

This puts `58, 40` on the stack, gets the length of the input stack, `2,` modulos by 2, `+` adds it to the `(`, `r` reverses, `oo` outputs two characters, and `~` terminates the program. [Try it here!](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/) Input is like `"somber"`. I don't think we need a GIF for this ;)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

Code:

```
':žuâ`¹gÉ@
```

Dammit, also 10 bytes: `gÉ40+ç':sJ`.

Uses **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=JzrFvnXDomDCuWfDiUA&input=ZGVsaWdodGVk).

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

Code:

```
”:³Lị“)(
```

Explanation:

```
”:         # The ":" character
  ³L       # Get the length of the input
    ị“)(   # Find the index of the length in the ")(" string.
           # Uses cyclic indexing for indices exceeding the length of the string.
```

Uses the [**Jelly-encoding**](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page).

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCdOsKzTOG7i-KAnCko&input=&args=Ymxlc3NlZA).

Answer (score 1):

## Fuzzy Octo Guacamole, 22 bytes

```
^!_2rm{':('0}i{':)'1}_
```

Gets input, finds `length%2`, prints `:)` vs `:(` for on a remainder of `1` or `0`.

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, <s>35</s> <s>34</s> 30 bytes

```
print(#(...)%2>0 and":)"or":(")
```

Comment: Use `<1` instead of `==0` to save a byte :)

Comment: use `(...)` instead of `io.read()` to save 3 bytes :)

Comment: `print(#(...)%2 and":)"or":(")` just skip the `<1` already

Comment: But `(...)` doesn't take input :(

Comment: But it's allowed.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript 30 bytes

```
a=>alert(a.length%2?":)":":(")
```

## Javascript return version 23 bytes

```
a=>a.length%2?":)":":("
```

Try it out:

```js
b=a=>a.length%2?":)":":("
alert(b(prompt("Please enter how you feel!")));
```

Comment: Since it's a function, I think you can just return the result.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ You need to output it.

Comment: See my javascript answer for what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1):

## Jolf, <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
+':."()"mρl
```

I <s>might (might) be</s> was able to golf it down a byte by joining the faces. [Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=Kyc6LiIoKSJtz4Fs&input=InNvbWJlciI)

### Explanation

```
+':."()"mρl
+':          ":" + 
   ."()"     the member from "()"
        mρl  that is the parity of the length of the implicit input
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Labyrinth](https://github.com/mbuettner/labyrinth), 14 bytes

```
4
1
#$
;,98..@
```

[Try it online!](http://labyrinth.tryitonline.net/#code=NAoxCiMkCjssOTguLkA&input=bWVsYW5jaG9seQ)

#### Explanation

Labyrinth primer:

- Labyrinth has two stacks of arbitrary-precision integers, *main* and *aux*(iliary), which are initially filled with an (implicit) infinite amount of zeros.
- The source code resembles a maze, where the instruction pointer (IP) follows corridors when it can (even around corners). The code starts at the first valid character in reading order, i.e. in the top left corner in this case. When the IP comes to any form of junction (i.e. several adjacent cells in addition to the one it came from), it will pick a direction based on the top of the main stack. The basic rules are: turn left when negative, keep going ahead when zero, turn right when positive. And when one of these is not possible because there's a wall, then the IP will take the opposite direction. The IP also turns around when hitting dead ends.
- Digits are processed by multiplying the top of the main stack by 10 and then adding the digit. If the top of the stack is negative, the digit is subtracted instead.

The code starts in the top left corner, with the IP moving south. The `41` simply turns the top `0` on the main stack into `41`, the character code of `)`.

We now enter a 2x2 (clockwise) loop which reads one character at a time, and toggles the top of the stack between `40` (`(`) and `41` (`)`):

```
#   Push the stack depth, which is 1.
$   XOR the top two values on the stack, toggling between 40 and 41.
,   Read a character (positive value) or -1 at EOF. At EOF, we exit the loop.
;   Discard the character.
```

At the end of the loop, the main stack has the correct character code for either `(` or `)` and a `-1` on top of that. The rest of the code is linear.

```
98  Turn the -1 on top of the stack into -198.
.   Print the top of the stack, modulo 256. -198 % 256 == 58, the character
    code of ':'.
.   Print the top of the stack, i.e. the mouth of the emoticon.
@   Terminate the program.
```

Comment: Magic, magic numbers.

Comment: @KennyLau `)`'s char code is 41, so I bet it has something to with that.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root#Overview_of_the_code

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript ES6, 23 bytes

```
x=>":"+"()"[x.length%2]
```

Simple anonymous function.

### Test

```js
f = x => ":" + "()" [x.length % 2];
makeRow = (x, y) => t.innerHTML += `<tr><td>${x}</td><td>${y}</td></tr>`;
`contented
delighted
merry
overjoyed
pleased
blessed
chipper
content
convivial
gleeful
gratified
intoxicated
jolly
light
peppy
perky
playful
sparkling
sunny`.split(`\n`).forEach(e => makeRow(e, f(e)));

t.innerHTML += "<tr><th colspan=2>Sad cases</th></tr>";

`melancholy
bitter
somber
dismal
mournful
blue
dejected
despairing
despondent
disconsolate
distressed
down
downcast
gloomy
glum
heavyhearted
lugubrious
morbid
morose
troubled
bereaved`.split(`\n`).forEach(e => makeRow(e, f(e)));
```

```css
html {
  font-family: Consolas, monospace;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td,
th {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table id="t">
  <tr>
    <th>Word</th>
    <th>Output</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan=2>Happy cases</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what is the type of `x`?

Comment: @KennyLau `x` is a string.

Comment: javascript does not require `x.length()`?

Comment: @KennyLau Nope, `.length` is a method that changes with the object.

Comment: It's shorter to just use ":(" or  ":)"

Comment: @Bálint No, they're the same length last i checked.

Comment: It's 23 bytes if I can count correctly. That's why I felt it strange. They should be the same length, but mine was a byte shorter.

Comment: @Bálint You can count correctly. I had the wrong score up >_>